# What's the UTTypeIdentifier for Safari Extension files? .safariextz

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extension

You know, like `com.apple.safari.bookmark` for Safari Bookmarks, or `com.apple.ical.ics` for iCal calendars.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not defined. Open `/Application/Safari.app/Contents/Info.plist` by the plist editor and check the list of the exported UTIs.
Or you can directly check the LaunchServices database from the command line using

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister
```

Comment: I guess Apple is lazy. File a bug report! That's the only way to convince Apple to do that.